# Reinitializing NivoSlider after simulating destroy

Tags: jquery, initialization, nivo-slider

nivoslider doesn't include a destroy or initializing method. after simulating destroy using the following code:

```
$('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;
$('#slider').find('div.nivo-slice').remove();
$('#slider').find('div.nivo-caption').remove();
$('#slider').find('div.nivo-controlNav').remove();
$('#slider').removeAttr("style");
$('#slider').empty();                               
$(window).unbind('keypress');
```

and using `$('#silder').nivoSlider()` again it get stuck at the first image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507466/nivoslider-update-or-restart-or-even-destroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the best way is to forget about all the destroying thing and replace the silder with it's initial state. suppose the initial state of silder is:

```
<div id="silder" class="nivoSlider"></div>
```

Then the best way to do the destroying and initializing at one step is to do something like:

```
$('#silder').replaceWith('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>');
```